# Bootstrap 3 Popover arrow and box positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am using `Bootstrap 3` popovers to display information about a link on hover, before clicking the link.

It's currently working at the moment, however, The links are displayed from a dropdown menu at the top of the page.

When the first link has a lot of information about it, the top of the popover disappears at the top of the page, so you cannot see the content of it.

I am trying to make it so that the popover arrow appears at the top-left of the popover(as opposed to middle-left which it is doing now) and the top of the popover box is level with the arrow if that makes sense.

```
$('.popOver').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    html: true
});
```

This above is working fine but I don't believe any popover options are able to help me here. Its the CSS I need to change but it's rather extensive to post, so I was just looking for someone with knowledge of bootstrap to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can customize the placement of the popover or it's arrow my manipulating the `.popover` CSS once the popover is shown.

For example, this pushes the top of the popover down 22 pixels..

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $('.popover').css('top',parseInt($('.popover').css('top')) + 22 + 'px')
})
```

**Working demo**: http://bootply.com/88325

Comment: @BeepDog the bootstap events in 3.0 are namespaced with 'bs', try listening for 'shown.popover' instead

Comment: This is partially working for me. When I click on the input the popover loads on the top and after some milliseconds it moves down. Why? =(

Comment: If you are using default container settings you should modify only currently shown popover, not every `.popover`:  
`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {  
            $(this).next().css('top',parseInt($(this).next().css('top')) + 22 + 'px');  
        });`

Comment: That's right @RicardoGreen as this question is for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thanks @Zim, anyways can you help me with this edit suggestion for this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22460271

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using the placement method rather than the `shown.bs.popover` event.
This will not trigger a popover jump when the element is shown.

This is how it works:

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
  placement: function(context, source) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() { 
      self.$arrow.css('top', 55);
      self.$tip.css('top', -45);
    }, 0);
    return 'right';
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My use case is that the popover placement is `top` and I have to remove the arrow.

I followed the solution provided by @Skelly while I was using bootstrap 3.2.0.
One problem is that the popover flash as the css property `top` is updated in the `shown.bs.popover`.

In fact, you can override the `template` property when initializing the popover and add some `margin-top` (`margin-left` if the placement is left/right) to it.

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
  placement: 'top',
  template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip" style="margin-top:10px;"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
});
```

demo: http://www.bootply.com/gWwmO5XdbL

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the popover going above so I couldn't see it. This fixed it for me

```
// Move things around if the popover is clipped on top.
if (parseInt($('.popover').position().top) < 10) {
  var arrow_position = parseInt($(this).position().top);
  $('.popover').css('top', 10 + 'px');
  $('.popover .arrow').css('top', arrow_position + 'px');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> It will provide exact position to ur arrow

```
 $(el).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var position = parseInt($('.popover').position().top);
    var pos2 = parseInt($(el).position().top) - 5;
    var x = pos2 - position + 5;
     if (popoverheight < x)
     x = popoverheight;
     $('.popover.left .arrow').css('top', x + 'px');
    });
```

Comment: how to get the popoverheight ?