# Shift bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have an input element within a bootstrap panel.
I would like to show the bootstrap popover of the input element outside of the panel.

My html:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="text" id="text_input" data-toggle="popover"
        data-content="blah" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="left"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();

    /*
    $("#text_input").on("shown.bs.popover", function(){

          $(".popover").css("left", 
          parseInt($(".popover").css("left")) - 20 + "px");

      });
    */
});
```

my css:

```
.panel {
    width:50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10430/
(uncomment js to see desired result)

In order to do this I would like to shift the popover element left.
I tried doing this as outlined here:
[Bootstrap Popover arrow and box positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427857/bootstrap-popover-arrow-and-box-positioning)
But this causes the popover to jump from the original position to the new position when it is shown. (for some reason this doesn't happen on fiddle, it happens when I run the code on my server).

An example of what I want done can be found on stackoverflow.
When you click on "add a comment" and you don't have enough reputation points, a tooltip is displayed. But rather than being displayed directly to the right/bottom/left/top of the element, it is displayed far to the right:

[image: popover far right example]

Are there any suggestions on how to achieve this effect of shifting the position of the popover?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `+ "px"` from js code.

Below snippet should work.

```
$("#text_input").on("shown.bs.popover", function(){

      $(".popover").css("left", 
      parseInt($(".popover").css("left")) - 20);

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10432/

Comment: Check the jsfiddle. The popover has shifted 20 pixels to left. Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: The fiddle works, but not when I run it on my server

Comment: Did you try clearing browser cache? Also hard refresh the page `Ctrl + F5`